# I've updated the Bios but I still get an error when installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

For days now I've been trying to install Ubuntu along side windows 10 on my Dell laptop but failing. I was getting an errata error telling me to update the microcode. So after reading a few solutions I managed to update the Bios to the latest version. I also partitioned one of my hard drives (F) and allocated over 70GB. However I'm still failing to install Ubuntu alongside windows using a bootable USB stick. When I boot my machine from the USB, the process kind of starts but brings an error saying I need to update microcode, it then automatically skips that an continues to the next page where I'm to select to install or try Ubuntu. I click install, it goes ahead but when it reaches the menu where I should select "install along windows", that option isn't available. Instead I have like 3 options; Install Ubuntu and erase windows; and other options but doesn't give me the option to install along windows. Please help. How do I do about this?